# PyAudio raise exception on buffer under/overflow

Tags: python, audio, portaudio, pyaudio

PyAudio is based on PortAudio. Is there anyway to detect a buffer under/overflow for writing/reading from an audio stream in PyAudio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/) you can raise an exception on underflow when doing a write on a Stream class:

`Stream.write(self, frames, num_frames=None, exception_on_underflow=True)`

Comment: I haven't gotten this to work. This code ( http://pastie.org/3147232 ) is similar to an example on the PyAudio page with a silly for-loop to induce buffer underflows, but no exception gets thrown. I do hear the breaks in the audio, though.

Comment: When I tried your pastie code on OS X, I got an underflow exception.